# Can't find Users Downloads Folder

Tags: python, path, operating-system

**Background**

I am trying to write an output file to a network drive dir, in addition to the users `Downloads` folder, which is where I am running into challenges...

**Code**
I am trying to achieve the desired output by accessing the users `Downloads` folder as follows:

```
downloads_folder_file = str(f'C:\\Users\\{os.getlogin()}\\Downloads\\Output_File_.xlsx')
```

**Issue**
When the code attempts to write, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\WILLIA~1.FOR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\39\\openpyxl.a_ys6_1g'
```

Whilst I obviously understand what `FileNotFoundError` means, I don't understand why I am not getting into the `Downloads` folder, which I can access through `File Explorer` as follows:
`C:\Users\username\Downloads`

**What I've tried**
When I print `downloads_folder_file` I do correctly get back `C:\Users\username\Downloads\`

Is there anything glaringly obvious that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Try adding debug `print(downloads_folder_file)` to check it's actual content during code execution, because what's in the error msg and your attempt is different?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, confirming when I print I do get back ``C:\Users\username\Downloads\`` I'll add to my question to be clearer.

Comment: It's better to print the whole Traceback message plus more chunk of your code.

Comment: Gonna go out on a limb and say your issue has nothing to do with the line of code you posted (`c:\users\...\download\...`) and is happening before or after it. Your code is clearly trying to access something called `openpyxl.a_ys6_1g` and not finding it. Are you getting a line number with that error? does it match up to anything in your code?